# Task creation from QuickAction giving error when I'm pre-defining 'assign to' value using formula and also app is closing in FSL app

Tags: field-service-lightning, fsl

I am trying to create a task from Work Order using Quick Action where Task will be assigned to the Supervisor of the Technician who's creating the task.
I am pre-defining 'Assigned to' value in Quick action with one related field from Work Order.
[image]

When I'm creating the task from the FSL app , It's getting created and Assigned to Supervisor but also showing error.

[image]
[image]

I have checked object and field permission from Profile and access is there. If I remove the Assign to field then it's not giving any issue.
Also when I'm clicking on the 'Assign to' field to select another user the app is just crashing and closing.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm receiving the same field service crash when trying to change the "Assign to" field. Have you find any solution?